# ASP.NET MVC Website first start

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, machine.config

Hello i am currently learning ASP.NET MV4 with Visual Studio 2012, i created a new project, not an empty project, an internet application but anytime i try to run it i keep getting an error.

There is no much else i can say about this, i am just now learning ASP.NET with Razor.
I would very much appreciate some help on this.  The error itself seems to be originating from my machine.config file but i'm kinda afraid of opening that file.

This is the error:

```
http://prntscr.com/3a6ltl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add MySQL.Web as your reference with NuGet `Install-Package MySql.Web`.

Or remove the red line from your machine.config if you are not going to use the MySQL Membership provider

It is located here: `c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config`

Comment: The error is not coming from my web.config but rather from my machine.config

Comment: It shouldnt be in your machine.config in the first place. Remove the line there. I still think it's in your web.config, it just shows machine.config because that is the configuration loading order

Comment: No nothing like that in my web.config i checked

Comment: Remove it from the machine.config then, it is located here: `c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config`

Comment: Thank you i decided not to remove it but rather comment it since i do not know how it got there in the first place.